# Database Connection with Json Object Value Null

Tags: android, arrays, json

// I have already jSON file when i called this method its given null value on it.

```
 new load_customername().execute();
```

Use this method to call below class

```
public class load_customername extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
       //String i = args[0];

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
       // params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_Customer_Name, i));

        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_get_customername, "GET", params);

        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {


            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();


        }
        return null;
    }


}
```

}

Comment: Is null what you expected to get? If not, what did you expect to get? We are not mind readers here.

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask runs in worker thread, you won't get response instantly. Use onPostExecute with callBack to read the response.

Comment: still not work.this{Plan_Cancellation_Activity$load_customer_list@4455} 
args = {String[0]@4477} 
params = {ArrayList@4482}  size = 0
url_get_customerlist = "http://192.168.1.18/EYC/get_customername.php"
json = null
jParser = {JSONParser@4479}